# Capistrano and Readline user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, terminal, capistrano

I have a script that prompts for user input via `Readline.readline`. I'd like to execute it remotely via Capistrano, but it seems like cap doesn't play nice with Readline. Is there any other way to prompt for user input in an executed script? I need to be able to execute the script outside of cap, so I can't make it a cap task and use `ask`.

Here's the script:

```
unless User.find_by(is_administrator: true)
  user_name = Readline.readline("Enter your name: ", true)
  user_email = Readline.readline("Enter your email: ", true)

  user = User.create!({ name: user_name, email: user_email, is_administrator: true })
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano is not intended to run scripts that require interactive input. My recommendation would be to change your approach. For example, you could prompt for the information you need locally (i.e. with `ask`), and then use that information to generate a script that you upload and execute remotely.

That said, there is a low-level extension point in Capistrano that allows some possibility of interactivity. It will require you to run a lot of custom code, but there is some documentation on the subject:

https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#interactive-commands

> in some cases, you may want to programmatically drive interaction with a command and this can be achieved by specifying an `:interaction_handler` option when you `execute`, `capture` or `test` a command.